# Can't access IIS through public IP address

Tags: iis, iis-10

I've googled a lot for this, but haven't found anyone with a problem exactly like mine, or hasn't been described like mine. The answers from those questions, which I've tried, haven't worked.

First, I have no firewall running (just while testing this)

I can access my site by `127.0.0.1`, and my local ip, `10.0.0.124`, but I can't access it by my public IP.

I have port 80 forwarded, and have confirmed that with canyouseeme.org. The port only responds while IIS is running (start/stop) on this machine.

I added my public IP as to netsh `netsh http add iplisten 0.0.0.0` (where `0.0.0.0` is my actual IP address) of course. Doing that made IIS unable to start, til I also added `127.0.0.1`.

Still, no matter what I do, I get `[IP Address] took too long to respond,` while the site loads promptly on local IP addresses. The same is true for domains pointed at my PC via Windows' `hosts` file.

Answer (score 0):

**I solved this.**

Everything works fine, even with a properly configured firewall. The problem is that port-forwarding doesn't work within the network.

"Hairpinning", essentially local port-forwarding, does not appear to be supported by my ISP's modem.

I disconnected my phone from my wifi, hit my ip address, and my website came right up.

It's a pretty easy answer, but it might save someone else trouble in understanding what's actually happening.

My workaround is pointing my domain at my computer, and using `hosts` to point my domain at `127.0.0.1` at my public IP. This is just for a very small website anyway.